# adding code to jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I want to add a very simple bit of code to a jsfiddle, but when ever I do it breaks everything else.  This is the code I'd like to add:

```
$("#launcher").click(function(){
  $("#profile_850_HEADER").animate({
    margin-top: "10px"
}, 1500 );
});
```

and this is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/F3wjg/3/ , I'm sure this is beyond simple but I can't figure it out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the console: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: One of the reasons I like http://jsbin.com over jsfiddle. It tells you all the errors/warnings below your JS code. http://jsbin.com/iwasud/1/edit `Line 3: margin-top: "10px" --- Expected ':' and instead saw '-'.` You can also open the JS console in your browser to see the error.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot, that's actually a super helpful tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`margin-top: "10px"` should be:

```
 marginTop: "10px"
```

Or

```
 'margin-top': "10px"
```

Or simply (my preferred):

```
 marginTop: 10
```

The unquoted `-` (minus/hyphen sign) is not allowed in property names and results in a syntax error.

Comment: Not so obvious, as jQuery does the CSS-to-JS camelCasing for you, many of my friends have ran in the same issue with `.animate` in the past. `=]`

Comment: one more question, how do you keep the speed at 1500 but also make the animate "ease" in?

Comment: Ease in as in FadeIn? Or what kind of easing?

Comment: eh, looks like you need a plugin for that right?  Easeing isn't built into jquery.  I had wanted the first one to animate in, delay half a second or so then animate the rest, I had done this but doesn't seem to delay

Comment: $("#launcher").click(function(){
  $("#profile_850_HEADER").animate({
    marginTop: 10
}, 600);
      $("#profile_850_BIO").animate({
    marginTop: 10
}, 600).delay(600);
      $("#profile_850_EDU").animate({
    marginTop: 10
}, 600);
      $("#profile_850_CONTACT").animate({
    marginTop: 10
}, 600);
    
    
});

Comment: If you mean the easing effects listed [here](http://jqueryui.com/effect/#easing) you need to include either the jQuery UI or the [easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/). By default, jQuery has 2 easings, `swing` (default) and `linear`, you can apply them in the 4th parameter if the `.animate`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3wjg/6/) with linear.

Comment: Now if you just want to wait 'til one animation finishes 'til you start another, you just put inside the callback. Sec while I make a fiddle.

Comment: Here's the fiddle using callbacks - http://jsfiddle.net/F3wjg/10/ (it can be optimized a bit but this one is simple for understanding)

Comment: hey thanks so much for helping me, everything you said made sense so thanks

Comment: I did ended up figuring out the delay, I like the way it looks slightly better, is there a reason the thing I did here http://jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/F3wjg/11/ wouldn't make as much sense as what you did here http://jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/F3wjg/12/

Comment: Yup looks better than mine. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

Wat is tis

```
margin - top: "10px"
```

Supposed to be

```
marginTop : '10px'
```

Answer (score 0):

use  `marginTop: "10px"` instead of `margin-top: "10px"`